# VBA paste defined message follow by excel paste range into outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

The VBA code is suppose to

1. Paste the defined text into email body [emailMessage]
2. Next, paste the excel range [filteredRange] below the defined text into the email body.

   However, the VBA code paste 2) follow by 1) in this sequence. I'm unable to correct this.

   Code:

   ```
       ' Loop through each filter criteria and apply the filter
       For Each criteria In filterValues
           filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues

           ' Copy the visible range to a new worksheet and resize it to fit the content
           Dim filteredRange As Range
           Set filteredRange = filterRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

           ' Check if any visible cells were found
           If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
               ' Create a new email
               Dim outlookApp As Object
               Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

               Dim outlookMail As Object
               Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

               ' Define the email message
               Dim emailMessage As String
               emailMessage = "Hi, please find below the summary for " & criteria & " Cash Pool " & ws.Range("C1") & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

               ' Define the folder path where attachments are
               Dim folderPath As String
               folderPath = "C:\Users\qte3004\Desktop\SG\"

               ' Check if the folder exists
               If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
                   ' Loop through all the files in the folder
                   Dim fileName As String
                   fileName = Dir(folderPath & criteria & "*.*")
                   Do While fileName <> ""
                       ' Attach each file with name starting with the criteria to the email
                       outlookMail.Attachments.Add folderPath & fileName
                       fileName = Dir()
                   Loop
               End If


               ' Copy the filtered range and paste it into the email body
               filteredRange.Copy
               Dim wordDoc As Object
               Set wordDoc = outlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
               wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
               wordDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf & emailMessage

               ' Check if the criteria is present in the dictionary
               If recipientsDict.Exists(criteria) Then
                   ' Retrieve the recipient list associated with the criteria
                   Dim recipients As String
                   recipients = recipientsDict(criteria)
                   ' Add the recipient list to the email
                   outlookMail.To = recipients
                   outlookMail.CC = criteriaSheet.Range("H2")
               End If

               outlookMail.Subject = criteria & " Cash Pool " & ws.Range("C1")
               outlookMail.Display

           End If
   ```

Tried to swap the code from:

1. ```
               wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
               wordDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf & emailMessage
   ```

   into:

   results: no emailmessage. paste range values is not showing too.
2. ```
   wordDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf & emailMessage
   ```
3. ```
   wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
   ```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the emailmessage value inside the .body

```
    outlookMail.Body = "Hi, please find below the summary for " & criteria & " Cash Pool " & ws.Range("C1") & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Dim wordDoc As Object, x
    Set wordDoc = outlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    x = wordDoc.Range.End - 1
    filteredRange.Copy
    wordDoc.Range(x).Paste
```

Comment: hi @k1dr0ck, thanks! it works. I have been getting run-time error "Method 'AutoFilter' of object 'Range failed'. Can you also advise how i can resolve this error prompt?

Comment: @HuiM it is best to post another question post your code, be specific of what you are trying to do, show which line in the code has the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the `Start` and `End` properties of the `Range` class where to paste text and data/images. The [Document.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.range) method returns a `Range` object by using the specified starting and ending character positions.

Note, you can use a macro recorder available in Word to get the code generated for you, so you could re-use properties and methods in your automation code. See [Create or run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) for more information.